# Need to search a comma contained line in a file and want to replace it with its before line

Tags: shell-script

I have a file test.txt and in that few lines have single comma as below.

```
$ cat test.txt
ABCD
Test,plan
Sample
Working
Tester,Developer
Learn
Teach
Study
Coding
Stack,exchange
```

Need output as below:

```
ABCD
ABCD
Sample
Working
Working
Learn
Teach
Study
Coding
Coding
```

I'm unable to find the way using unix command to print as above Kindly, Please let me know how to deal this comma line search and replace it with above line.

Tried as below for searching not sure on replacing:

```
#Searching comma
sed -i 's/,/replace_above_line/g' test.txt
```

I want to replace globally with prior line in the file where ever line has comma.

Comment: You mean that you want to replace the string that has a comma with the whole word that becomes before it. Is the comma always surrounded with alphabetical characters or can it be surrounded with numeric or special characters?

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, you'd need to hold two lines in the pattern space - for example

```
sed -i -e '$!N;s/\(.*\)\n.*,.*/\1\n\1/' -e 'P;D' file
```

Alternatively, using `ed`, you could mark each line preceding the comma lines (`g/,/-1`), then copy them (`t`) and go back and delete the original (`-1d`):

```
$ ed -s file
g/,/-1t\
-1d
wq
```

or as a one-liner:

```
printf '%s\n' g/,/-1t\\ -1d wq | ed -s file
```